# invalid type error calling method from test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

Trying to call a Class method from a test class:

Class UtilHelper

```
 global class FeeWrapper {
        global List<Project__c> transToUpdate;
    }

 public static FeeWrapper PassingRentFee(Fee_Calculation__c Config, Project__c trans, List<Project__c> transToUpdate, Map<String, Fee_Mapping__c> m_Fee)
```

Test class

```
 Map<String,Fee_Mapping__c > afMap = new Map<String,Fee_Mapping__c >(
            [ SELECT Id, Fee_Amount__c , _Fee_Basis__c , WO__c,Group__c,Type__c,Macro_Type__c 
              FROM Fee_Mapping__c]);
 List<Fee_Calculation__c > feeRec = [
                SELECT Id, Name
                FROM Fee_Calculation__c];
 List<Project__c> projectRec = [
                SELECT Id, Name
                FROM sProject__c];
    
UtilHelper.PassingRentFee rcp = new UtilHelper.PassingRentFee(feeRec[0],projectRec[0],projectRec,afMap); ***error Invalid type***
```

Is it the parameter I am passing in or is it my syntax.  Or both that is causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line contains three errors.

```
UtilHelper.PassingRentFee rcp = new UtilHelper.PassingRentFee(...);
```

1. Invoking `new` to create an instance requires parentheses:

   ```
    UtilHelper.PassingRentFee rcp = new UtilHelper().PassingRentFee(...);
   ```
2. The name of the inner class is `FeeWrapper`, not `PassingRentFee`.
3. But your method is `static` and is not called on an instance at all, but on the class.

The final version should be

```
    UtilHelper.FeeWrapper rcp = UtilHelper.PassingRentFee(...);
```

Comment: Thank you David. Ok.  So method is Static therefore syntax should be:  
 `UtilHelper.PassingRentFee rcp =  UtilHelper.PassingRentFee(feeRec[0],projectRec[0],projectRec[0],afMap);`  If this still throws an Invalid type error should I be looking at my parameters?

Comment: Could you edit the complete text of the error into your question?

Comment: Here is the error  "Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: UtilHelper.PassingRentFee".  Does the global feewrapper Class need to be taken in account?

Comment: The name of the inner class is wrong. See above.

Comment: ok so the feewrapper does come into play.  Made update :"UtilHelper.FeeWrapper rcp = UtilHelper.PassingRentFee(feeRec[0],projectRec[0],projectRec[0],afMap);".  New error is "Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void PassingRentFee (Fee_Calculation__c, Project__c, Project__c, Map<String,Fee_Mapping__c>) from the type UtilHelper"

Comment: Third parameter was incorrect.  Needed list not record.  Thanks David